# LINQ query with Distinct and WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

My Distinct query is working fine, but I need to put a WHERE clause in another method.

This is my working query for retrieving distinct managers

```
public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetDistinctMgrs()
{
    IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> managers = EmpCache.EmployeeList.GroupBy(x => x.MgrID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
    return managers;
}
```

Here is where I am trying to squeeze WHERE to get employee's manager from distinct list of managers. But with WHERE clause I get "Enumeration yielded no results"

```
public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetDefaultMgr(string EMPID)
{
    IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> manager = EmpCache.EmployeeList
            .Where(s => s.EmpID == EMPID)
            .GroupBy(x => x.MgrID)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

     return manager; //<- "Enumeration yielded no results"
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with that query... but did you verify that your employee list actually contains an instance that has an `EmpID` with whatever value you're passing?

Comment: Is the ID a number or a string?  Is EmpID and EMPID both the same type?

Comment: `==` is case sensitive, also it would be unusual to not use number as an ID (unless it is an exceedingly special circumstance in your business logic)

Comment: TheGeneral, Thanks for pointing out about case sensitivity. ToUpper() did the trick

Comment: Is there any way I select just the MgrID from Select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it

```
 public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetDefaultMgr(string EMPID)
 {
               IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> manager = 
               from mng in EmpCache.EmployeeList
                where mng.EmpID.ToLower() == EMPID.ToLower()
                orderby mng.MgrID
                select mng;
               return manager;
    }
```

or

```
public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetDefaultMgr(string EMPID)
{
    IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> manager = EmpCache.EmployeeList
            .Where(s => s.EmpID.ToLower() == EMPID.ToLower())
            .GroupBy(x => x.MgrID)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

     return manager; //<- "Enumeration yielded no results"
}
```

Based in your new question

```
 public static  string GetDefaultMgr(string EMPID)
    {
       string managerID = EmpCache.EmployeeList
                .Where(s => s.EmpID.ToLower() == EMPID.ToLower())
                .GroupBy(x => x.MgrID)
        .Select(x => x.MgrID).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

         return managerID; //<- "Enumeration yielded no results"
    }
```

Comment: The query works. Can someone please guide how to return just one field MgrID instead of whole object?

Comment: is it a string?

Comment: something like it I dont know your objects well to know the right property name

Comment: didn't work. I was thinking if LINQ could return single field in the Select, but couldn't figure out

Comment: simple after the select do another select .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList().select(x=> x.EmpID.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is sending a reqest to the db and when the request is finished you do your groupby etc.

so when the db return nothing you get the exception

here is how i would do it

```
public static IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> GetDefaultMgr(string EMPID)
 {
  IEnumerable<DTO.Employee> manager = EmpCache.EmployeeList
            .Where(s => s.EmpID == EMPID)
             .GroupBy(x => x.MgrID);
           if(manager?.Count()>0)
            return manager.Select(x => x.First());

       return null;
    }
```